# Using EJML, is there a quick way to find mean of columns of a matrix?

Tags: ejml

Was looking for a function which returns a one diamensional SimpleMatrix giving the mean.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a built in function to do that.  This should do the trick though:

```
SimpleMatrix ones = new SimpleMatrix(1,10);
ones.set(1);
SimpleMatrix m = SimpleMatrix.random64(10,20,-1,2,new Random());

SimpleMatrix sum = ones.mult(m);
SimpleMatrix mean = sum.divide(10);
```